# PendingIntent to update sqlite

Tags: android-intent, android-service, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm fairly new to Android GCM and notification thing. Now, I'm stuck at how to **update sqlite when user tab a button in notification**

The scenario is

1. My server will send gcm to GCM server
2. GCM server send message to device
3. Once IntentService received message, create new message record in local sqlite.
4. Create new notification view in notification bar with 2 button, "Launch app", "Mark as read" and "Dismiss"

The "Launch app" button is simple, every tutorial will show how to start new activity by using PendingIntent. But for "Mark as read" and "Dismiss" I don't know how to implement it (And English isn't my mother language, I can't come up with the keyword to search for an answer .... So, sorry if this question has been ask before)

- For "Mark as read" button, I want it call a service or application subclass to update sqlite and then cancel the notification without having to launch an activity
- For "Dismiss" button, I want it to just cancel the notification

This is the code that have

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Title of the notification");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText("The message that I want to show"));
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, UNIQUE_ID, i1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    PendingIntent pi2 = null; // To mark as read, I don't how to write it yet.
    PendingIntent pi3 = null; // To dismiss, I don't how to write it yet.

    builder.addActon(R.drawable.launch_app_icon, "Launch app", pi1);
    builder.addActon(R.drawable.mark_as_read_icon, "Mark as read", pi2);
    builder.addActon(R.drawable.dismiss_icon, "Dismiss", pi3);

    Notification notification;
    if (DeviceHelper.getAndroidSDK() < 16) {
        notification = builder.getNotification();
    } else {
        notification = builder.build();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification);        
}
```

I also tried to set pi2 to be like this

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(MyApp.USER_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION);
PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, UNIQUE_ID, i2, PendingIntent.FLAG_ON_SHOT);
```

And then listen to local broadcast in Application subclass

```
public final class MyApp extends Application {
    public static final USER_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION = "UserDismissNotification";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Local broadcast received, update database
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(USER_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION));
    }
}
```

But the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive never get called.

Any suggestion are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it works as following

A. Create BroadcastReceiver

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.i("Dev", "Received");
    }
}
```

B. Register receive to Application object **

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity" />

    <receiver android:name="com.example.NotificationReceiver" /> 
</application>
```

C. create pending intent as following and add it to notification

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, UNIQUE_ID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

notification.addAction(R.drawable.button_icon, "Do something", pi);
```

Now, when user tab a button, NotifiationReceiver's onReceive will be called and then I can update db, launch activity or else base on parameter of intent bundle.

Hope this help

Comment: If you want to send intent to a broadcast receiver, you should use PendingIntent.getBroadcast method and not PendingIntent.getActivity